# "... already defined in *.obj" but im not defining any var twice in the same scope

Tags: c++, windows, global-variables

Im trying to get into gamehacking and started with a simple freecam hack.
after cleaning up some code and making functions and different files for some code I ran into a problems.
I always get the errors:

Ive already searched for the problem but dont find anything that resembles my problem most of them had multiple defines with the same name, but I do not have those,

I also commented out my global var in C--.cpp, and named my speed vars in FreeCamFunc.cpp to different names, but that didnt fixed it.

`C--.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include "FreeCamFunc.cpp"
using namespace std;

extern HANDLE g_program;

int main()
{
    double speed = 0.5;

    DWORD pid = 0x0000452C;
    g_program = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pid);

    LPVOID varAdress = (LPVOID)0x8CAC99E0;

    cout << "Ready" << endl;
    while (true) 
    {
        if (GetKeyState('Q') & 0x8000)
            IncY(varAdress, speed);
        if (GetKeyState('Z') & 0x8000)
            DecY(varAdress, speed);
    }
}
```

`FreeCamFunc.cpp`

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

HANDLE g_program;

void IncY(LPVOID varAdress, double speedup)
{
    double varValY = 0.0;
    ReadProcessMemory(g_program, varAdress, &varValY, sizeof(varValY), NULL);
    varValY += speedup;
    WriteProcessMemory(g_program, varAdress, (LPCVOID)& varValY, sizeof(varValY), NULL);
}

void DecY(LPVOID varAdress, double speeddown)
{
    double varValY = 0.0;
    ReadProcessMemory(g_program, varAdress, &varValY, sizeof(varValY), NULL);
    varValY -= speeddown;
    WriteProcessMemory(g_program, varAdress, (LPCVOID)& varValY, sizeof(varValY), NULL);
}
```

I expect everything to be fine because I only used one global var and any other var is in a scope but the errors say something different

```
"Fehler LNK2005 "void __cdecl DecY(void *,double)" (?DecY@@YAXPAXN@Z) ist bereits in C--.obj definiert. *\C--\FreeCamFunc.obj"
"Fehler LNK2005 "void __cdecl IncY(void *,double)" (?IncY@@YAXPAXN@Z) ist bereits in C--.obj definiert. *\C--\FreeCamFunc.obj"
"Fehler LNK2005 "void * g_program" (?g_program@@3PAXA) ist bereits in C--.obj definiert. *\C--\FreeCamFunc.obj"
```

saying: ... is already defined in c--.obj
and

```
Fehler  LNK1169 Mindestens ein mehrfach definiertes Symbol gefunden.    C-- *\C--.exe
```

saying: atleast one repeatedly defined symbol found

Comment: I throught it say that I want to use functions of that file

Comment: Usually, you include the header file, `#include "FreeCamFunc.h"`, not the .cpp file. You compile the .cpp file and link to its .obj file.

Comment: `#include` effectively places a copy of the included file in the including file. This means that everything--functions, variables, etc--defined in FreeCamFunc.cpp are duplicated in C--.cpp. Include header files. Compile cpp files. Then link the .obj files together. Your IDE does the latter two steps for you.

Comment: @Valon_Inc "_I throught it say that I want to use functions of that file_" How do you defined the word "use"? Since, `#include`, effectively, simply copy-pastes the contents of the file in `#include` directive, in-place of `#include` directive. Try doing this yourself. Now you see, why there's multiple definitions having the same name?

Comment: yes it worked, much thanks and sorry for this beginner problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to include header files not source files.  You should also separate your definitions and declarations into proper cpp and hpp files.  I have done so for you here:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include "FreeCamFunc.h"
using namespace std;

extern HANDLE g_program;

int main()
{
    double speed = 0.5;

    DWORD pid = 0x0000452C;
    g_program = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pid);

    LPVOID varAdress = (LPVOID)0x8CAC99E0;

    cout << "Ready" << endl;
    while (true) 
    {
        if (GetKeyState('Q') & 0x8000)
            IncY(varAdress, speed);
        if (GetKeyState('Z') & 0x8000)
            DecY(varAdress, speed);
    }
}
```

**FreeCamFunc.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

void IncY(LPVOID varAdress, double speedup);

void DecY(LPVOID varAdress, double speeddown);
```

**FreeCamFunc.cpp**

```
#include "FreeCamFunc.h"

HANDLE g_program;

void IncY(LPVOID varAdress, double speedup)
{
    double varValY = 0.0;
    ReadProcessMemory(g_program, varAdress, &varValY, sizeof(varValY), NULL);
    varValY += speedup;
    WriteProcessMemory(g_program, varAdress, (LPCVOID)& varValY, sizeof(varValY), NULL);
}

void DecY(LPVOID varAdress, double speeddown)
{
    double varValY = 0.0;
    ReadProcessMemory(g_program, varAdress, &varValY, sizeof(varValY), NULL);
    varValY -= speeddown;
    WriteProcessMemory(g_program, varAdress, (LPCVOID)& varValY, sizeof(varValY), NULL);
}
```